# Count consecutive values in mysql

Tags: mysql

UPDATE: I should have mentioned, YES, I have search and attempted to apply many of the numerous examples, however none have given the desired outcome.

I am trying to count the number of consecutive values in a large data set using mysql.

I've tried using partitions however I don't get the correct outcome.

[Outcome: using partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL4NN.png)

The outcome I am looking for is

[Outcome: desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFpbK.png)

Here is a sample from the data set

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/283f102/1)

Can someone point me on how to get the desired outcome ?

Comment: Since this is MySQL, removing the snowflake-cloud-data-platform tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic `gaps and island` problem. The code should be self-explanatory, but here's the general idea in two steps:

1. Identify for each partition, start of a new block/island by
   comparing value in current row with the previous row
2. Use a windowed running sum to create the blocks/islands

---

```
with cte1 as
(select *, case when flagkey=lag(flagkey) over (partition by supplierkey, attributekey, productkey, locationkey order by datekey) then 0 else 1 end as island_start
 from t),

cte2 as
(select *, sum(island_start) over (partition by supplierkey, attributekey, productkey, locationkey order by datekey) as island
 from cte1)

select *, row_number() over (partition by island order by datekey) as outcome
from cte2
```